# initialCommands in consoleProject is not executing one or more imports

Tags: scala, sbt

Given these two inconspicuous lines of code…

```scala
import scala.sys.process._
def less(s: String) = ("code -" #< new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes)).!!
```

…defined like this…

```scala
lazy val consoleSupportSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  initialCommands in consoleProject := """import scala.sys.process._
    |def less(s: String) = ("code -" #< new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes)).!!""".stripMargin
)
```

…which eventually is added to the `root` project…

```scala
lazy val root =
  Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
    .settings(consoleSupportSettings)
```

scala seems to not *really*(*) execute the line `import scala.sys.process._`: When I fire up sbt and hop into `consoleProject` I am greeted by…

```
> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
<console>:19: error: value #< is not a member of String
       def less(s: String) = ("code -" #< new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes)).!!
                                       ^

[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Apr 29, 2021 10:58:09 AM
```

`success` indeed. NOT.

However, if I remove the setting…

```
> set initialCommands in consoleProject := ""
[info] Defining root/*:consoleProject::initialCommands
[info] The new value will be used by root/*:consoleProject
[info] Reapplying settings...
…
> consoleProject
```

…and then **manually** enter above code it works:

```
…
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_272).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> def less(s: String) = ("code -" #< new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes)).!!
less: (s: String)String
```

### Why is that and how do I fix this?

Worthy of note is that the sbt version is **0.13.8**, so not exactly hot off the press.

(*) fwiw I replaced `import scala.sys.process._` with `import scala.sys.processasdf._` and it, as expected, would complain that `processasdf` was not a member of `scala.sys`, so it's not as if the import was actually ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I still don't know **why**, it turns out that having the import **inside** the def rather than globally does the job:

```scala
initialCommands in consoleProject := """
  |def less(s: String) = {
  |  import scala.sys.process._
  |  ("code -" #< new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes)).!!
  |}
  |""".stripMargin
```